# Can't load 2 models in pycaffe

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to load several models in pycaffe so I can perform ensemble learning. I can load 1 model fine and perform tests on it, but when I try to load my second model it just stops.

I use the following code:

```
model_def_net0 = caffe_root + 'Dataset/net0/deploy.prototxt'
model_weights_net0 = caffe_root + 'Dataset/net0/net0_train_vgg_iter_250000.caffemodel'

net0 = caffe.Net(model_def_net0,      # defines the structure of the model
                model_weights_net0,  # contains the trained weights
                caffe.TEST)     # use test mode (e.g., don't perform dropout)



model_def_caffe = caffe_root + 'Dataset/caffenet/deploy_3.prototxt'
model_weights_caffe = caffe_root + 'Dataset/caffenet/caffenet_train_iter_150000.caffemodel'

net1 = caffe.Net(model_def_caffe,      # defines the structure of the model
                model_weights_caffe,  # contains the trained weights
                caffe.TEST)     # use test mode (e.g., don't perform dropout)
```

When I execute the code it will halt when trying to load `net1` with the following in the log:

```
I0516 18:29:39.718916  7339 net.cpp:411] data -> data
I0516 18:29:39.718942  7339 net.cpp:411] data -> label
```

Comment: if you only load the second model `net1` does it work? or halt?

Comment: why do you have `label` blob in a `deploy` net? are you sure `deploy_3.prototxt` is an actual "deploy" net, or does it have a data layer that for some reason halts?

Comment: I solved the problem. The reason is that both models used the same lmdb which did not allow concurrent read. So i just made of copy of the database.